# bash: copy files with the same pattern

Tags: python, bash, shell, cp

I want to copy files scattered in separate directories into a single directory.

```
find . -name "*.off" > offFile
while read line; do
  cp "${line}"  offModels #offModels is the destination directory
done < offFile
```

While the file `offFile` has 1831 lines, but `cd offModels` and `ls | wc -l` gives 1827. I think four files end with ".off" are not copied.

At first, I think that because I use the double quote in shell script, files with names which contain dollor sign, backtick or backslash may be missed. Then I find one file named $.... But how to find another three? After `cd offModels` and `ls > ../File`, I write a python script like this:

```
fname1="offFile" #records files scattered
with open(fname1) as f1:
  contents1=f1.readlines()
fname2="File"
with open(fname2) as f2:
  contents2=f2.readlines()
visited=[0]*len(contents1)
for substr in contents2:
  substr="/"+substr
  for i, string in enumerate(contents1):
    if string.find(substr)>=0:
      visited[i]=1
      break
for i,j in enumerate(visited):
  if j==0:
    print contents1[i]
```

The output gives four lines while they are wrong. But I can find all the four files in the destination directory.

**Edit**
As the comment and answers point out, there are four files with duplicated names with other four. One thing interest me now is that, with the bash script I used, the file with name `$CROSS.off` is copied. That really suprised me.

Comment: Maybe you have files with the duplicated name.

Answer (score 3):

Looks like you have files with the same filenames, and `cp` just overwrites them.
You can use the `--backup=numbered` option for `cp`; here is a one-liner:

```
find -name '*.off' -exec cp --backup=numbered '{}' '/full/path/to/offModels' ';'
```

The `-exec` option allows you to execute a command on every file matched; you should use `{}` to get the file's name and end the command with `;` (usually written as `\;` or `';'`, because bash treats semicolons as command separators).

Comment: Since you're using non-standard options to `cp` you might as well use the `-t` option and have a more efficient command: `find -name '*.off' -exec cp --backup=numbered -t '/full/path/to/offModels' '{}' +`.

Comment: @gniourf_gniourf What does `-t` mean? I googled and did not find documentation about it. And when I execute this command, it says: `cp: illegal option---`

Comment: @mizabrik It warns that `cp: illegal option-- usage: cp blala..`

Comment: @dudu: [here's the GNU `cp` man page](https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/cp-invocation.html) and the `-t` option is documented [here](https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/cp-invocation.html#index-_002dt-10). Regarding the error you obtain: which version of `cp` are you using? (are you on OS X?)

Comment: @gniourf_gniourf Yes, I'm on OS X yosemite (version10.10.5).

Comment: @dudu: then I guess you can't use any of these options.